# Connecting to multiple MySQL database in single php app

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I’m trying to connect multiple mysql databases to a single php web app. I’d like each user to be able to access a different database. Every database has same tables but I wouldn’t like userA to na able to access the data of userB, using the same app.

How do I do this for the user to login to their own database. I saw this below online which addressed similar tasks but I don’t know how to implement login into a database.

E.G.

```
if(user1){
  User1_db
}elseif(user2){
    User2_db
}
```

I need your help pls. Thanks

Comment: _but I don’t know how to implement login into a database_ Then maybe you should start with that.

Comment: How many users do you expect will be using your system?

Comment: At what moment 2years

Comment: At any time. Because if you want 1 database per user thats how many databases you must then manage/backup/restore etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can tell you how it went. The OP started with their new shiny app, hacked away a good deal, and then suddenly realized that it's a *single user* application. They just didn't have such an entity in their database. So now they are trying to find a detour. Not realizing that their next stop is making a *consolidated* balance of all users.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sounds very possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the main database where I store user databases. And then you could fetch user DB from the main database and connect. Pseudo code:

```
$user = $mainDbConnection->select(select * from users where id = 'user_id');

$userDbConnection = $db->connect($user->database);

 // And then use this connection...

$someDataFromUserDb = $userDbConnection->select('select ...');
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. So with this I can login into a personal database

Comment: Yes, this approach will help you to avoid unnecessary if conditions, and since all the user databases have the same structure you could write your code once for all your users.